# MySQL merge results into table from count of 2 other tables, matching ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 3 tables: model, model_views, and model_views2. In an effort to have one column per row to hold aggregated views, I've done a migration to make the model look something like this, with a new column for the views:

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id       | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
|  [...]        |               |      |     |         |                |
| views         | int(20)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is what the columns for model_views and model_views2 look like:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | smallint(5)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| model_id   | smallint(5)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| time       | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_address | varchar(16)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

model_views and model_views2 are gargantuan, both totalling in the tens of millions of rows each. Each row is representative of one view, and this is a terrible mess for performance. So far, I've got this MySQL command to fetch a count of all the rows representing single views in both of these tables, sorted by model_id added up:

```
SELECT model_id, SUM(c) FROM (
    SELECT model_views.model_id, COUNT(*) AS c FROM model_views
    GROUP BY model_views.model_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT model_views2.model_id, COUNT(*) AS c FROM model_views2
    GROUP BY model_views2.model_id)
AS foo GROUP BY model_id
```

So that I get a nice big table with the following:

```
+----------+--------+
| model_id | SUM(c) |
+----------+--------+
| 1        | 1451   |
| [...]    |        |
+----------+--------+
```

What would be the safest route for pulling off commands from here on in to merge the values of SUM(c) into the column model.views, matched by the model.id to model_ids that I get out of the above SQL query? I want to only fill the rows for models that still exist - There is probably model_views referring to rows in the model table which have been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` on your subquery:

```
UPDATE model
   JOIN (
       SELECT model_views.model_id, COUNT(*) AS c 
       FROM model_views
       GROUP BY model_views.model_id
       UNION ALL
       SELECT model_views2.model_id, COUNT(*) AS c 
       FROM model_views2
       GROUP BY model_views2.model_id) toupdate ON model.id = toupdate.model_id
SET model.views = toupdate.c
```